# MS Word, IF field code with dropdown box

Tags: ms-word

I'm trying to get the IF field code to work based on a selection in a drop-down box in a document.

The simplified version looks like this..

```
No. of people: (drop-down box)
one

There { if "{ REF Dropdown1 }" = "one" "is one person" "are many people" }
```

in the drop down box, the choices are "one" or "many"

For some reason, the situation above returns "There are many people" even though my selection is "one". { REF Dropdown1 } returns "one"

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some possibilities (I'm assuming that "Calculate on exit" is checked for the dropdown, which seems to be confirmed by the value you are seeing for { REF Dropdown }

1. You haven't used the special field code braces on the nested field
   (i.e. the { REF Dropdown1 } inside the { IF } field. i.e. you need
   the sort you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows.
2. The bookmark "Dropdown1" has been modified so it covers a bit more
   than the dropdown. That does seem to be possible in some
   circumstances, although I generally find that the bookmark is
   correctly re-applied if you go into the field properties dialog box,
   re-enter the bookmark name and click OK. If you use something like

   a{ REF Dropdown1 }b
3. you may be able to see any extra characters that are "covered" by
           the bookmark. The syntax in the IF field isn't quite what you have
           posted, e.g. there is a space before the inner "{" or some such.

Comment: my goodness, you're a life saver. I didn't use the special braces for the REF field, stupid me.